# Animating checkbox replace SVG with Font Awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbZGoQ?editors=110) here, that animates a checkbox. Currently is using a SVG for the tick, how can I replace it with a font? [example](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/check/).

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
  float: left;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
  float: left;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label ~ label {
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: -35px;
  top: -3px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: -35px;
  top: -3px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') no-repeat center center;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input id="ham" type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="ham">
  <label for="ham">Yay or Nay</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This feels like a 'code it for me' question. You seem to have 99% of the code you need, you just need to adapt it...and that's something you should at least **try** before asking SO.

Comment: You probably need [these](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) codes in the content ex: `\f107`

Comment: @Paulie_D - i tried the content way below, my issue was that i forgot to add the 'f' in content: 'f....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, and adjust the `left`, `top` and `font-size` values as needed.

```
input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f00c';
}
```

---

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
    float:left;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: monospace;
    float: left;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label ~ label {
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    top: -3px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f00c';
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    top: -3px;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<form method="post" action="/">
    <fieldset>
        <input id="ham" type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="ham">
        <label for="ham">Yay or Nay</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

Follow this [link](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) for how to include Font Awesome into your project.

Comment: Thanks, ill mark as the answer. Any idea how the background of the box can change on click?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Using Font Awesome Icons without  Tags](http://davidwalsh.name/font-awesome-tags) you can do something like this:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
  content: '\f00c';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -32px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

You of course have to load the `font-awesome` css librairy with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`