# ::before and ::after not rendering on firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, checkbox

I developed the code and reviewed it on Google Chrome. This fills the checked checkbox with color.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

**CSS**

```
input:checked::after {
   content: open-quote;
   background-color: red;
   font-size:9px;
   border:1px solid black;
   border-radius:3px;
   /* height: 10px; */
   padding-left: 8px;
}
```

But this code is not working on FF and IE.

The reason I figured out is that the ::after is not rendering on FF and IE.

Please suggest a solution.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/spidiweb/g9Lhxhb1/) is the JsFiddle Link

Please view this fiddle on firefox and IE to see the problem

Comment: it's also not possible to style checkbox, try style <label> instead see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31611737/483779).

Comment: @Pangloss [In IE it's very possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Teemu good to know, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I too got the answer with label. But I thought that it must happen on ff as it is happening on chrome. Chrome does not obey rules and allow that. Hard luck:(